# After login, How to use ajax post request in laravel?

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, token, csrf

I am working on Laravel5.5.

after login,  sometimes, I need to use ajax post request.
by the way, due to middleware(auth), ajax post can't pass in route.

I already double checked stackoverflow and other sites to fix this issue.
but it couldn't help me.

Also i try

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/csrf#csrf-x-csrf-token

It only works if i put in the exception of middleware but i think it's not a good idea.

I already used bellow things.

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">

<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

Comment: So what error are you getting, `TokenMismatchException`?

Comment: Your `$.ajaxSetup` does not seem to be within script tags.

Comment: @apokryfos Good catch, I assume OP just left the stock `bootstrap.js` as is and that should work - failure of indenting properly on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using JQuery for your AJAX then you have to manually pass the token along with your post requests data like this

```
var token = $("meta[name = 'csrf-token']").val();
$.ajax({
   url : '/test',
   type : 'post',
   data : {
       _token : token,
       msg : 'test message'
   },
   success : function(res){
       console.log(res);
   }
});
```

this should solve the problem for you

however I suggest that you use axios since laravel already uses it and this behavior would be done internally also JQuery is old fashioned one more advantage axios makes use of Javascript Promises

hope this helps